# To upload video to youtube in "private" mode using "yt gem"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, youtube-api

I am working on a `ruby on rails` project, where I need to upload a video to youtube in private mode. I am using `yt gem` for uploading video to youtube. I can able to upload video, where default `privacy_sttaus` is `public`. How to upload a video with `private` as a `privacy_status`

My model code is

```
account = Yt::Account.new refresh_token: user.google_refresh_token
account.upload_video self.file, title: self.title
```

I have gone through [yt_gem_documentation](https://fullscreen.github.io/yt/videos.html), but can't able to get the desired information

Comment: I think you can do it like so: `body = {
        :snippet => {
          :title => title,
        },
        :status => {
          :privacy_status => privacy_status
        }
      }`

Comment: @KevinEtore, its not working sir

Comment: `privacy_status` option should work https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt/blob/master/lib/yt/models/account.rb#L69